# Rails db:drop issue | no implicit conversion of nil into String | ' TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Let me tell you first that I have the user model containing the password_digest

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :thumbnail
      t.string :email
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :uid
      t.string :provider

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

But I decided to install the Devise with the same User model as below:

```
class AddDeviseToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def self.up
    change_table :users do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      #t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""
    end
    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
  end

  def self.down
    # By default, we don't want to make any assumption about how to roll back a migration when your
    # model already existed. Please edit below which fields you would like to remove in this migration.
    raise ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
  end
end
```

And I generate new migration to remove such password_digest as follows:

```
class RemovePasswordDigestFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    remove_column :users, :password_digest, :string
  end
end
```

But what happen is I cannot do rails db:seed

```
rails aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `password_digest=' for #<User id: nil, first_name: "Clifford", last_name: "Marshall", thumbnail: nil, email: "owner1@example.com", uid: nil, provider: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
Did you mean?  password_digest
/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/db/seeds.rb:18:in `<main>'
```

While my code db/seeds.rb:18:in is as follows:

```
owners = User.create([
                       {
                         first_name: 'Clifford',
                         last_name: 'Marshall',
                         email: 'owner1@example.com',
                         password: '12345678',
                         thumbnail: 'https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/men/50.jpg',
                       },
```

So now I'm trying to to the rails db:reset but seems like rails db:drop cannot proceed with the following error

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String
Couldn't drop database ''
rails aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of nil into String

Tasks: TOP => db:drop:_unsafe
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

And when I roll back once (only for the migration that used for removing password_digest) I can't do it more with the following error:

```
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/db/migrate/20221211120417_add_devise_to_users.rb:49:in `down'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration: ActiveRecord::IrreversibleMigration
/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/db/migrate/20221211120417_add_devise_to_users.rb:49:in `down'
```

Appreciate your help sir.

Comment: `Couldn't drop database ''`. Seems it tries to trop a database without a name, where `my_app_(development)` would be expected. Is the environment set up properly?

Comment: Thank you sir. Actually I removed it before to make my docker work but will bring it back and check the results.

Comment: Do you still reference `password` in your `db/seeds.rb`? Or do you still use `has_secure_password` in your `app/models/user.rb`?

Comment: Appreciate you two sir !! I can do the reset after adding the database under development and do the seed after removing has_secure_password from user model !!!! Thank you so much !!!